# Why is the static property B = ${A} not changing anymore when changing A?

Tags: groovy, static

**Question**

Why is the static property `PATH2` not changing after the other static property `PATH1` was assigned a new value?

See the `assert` in the example below.

**Example**

```
println "--- Original values ---"
println "Configuration.PATH1: ${Configuration.PATH1}"
println "Configuration.PATH2: ${Configuration.PATH2}"
println ""

println "--- Values after changing PATH1---"
Configuration.PATH1 = "c:\\test"
println "Configuration.PATH1: ${Configuration.PATH1}"
println "Configuration.PATH2: ${Configuration.PATH2}"
println ""
assert Configuration.PATH2 == "c:\\test\\subfolder"




class Configuration {
    static public String PATH1 = "c:\\production"
    static public String PATH2 = "${PATH1}\\subfolder"
}
```

**Output**

```
--- Original values ---
Configuration.PATH1: c:\production
Configuration.PATH2: c:\production\subfolder

--- Values after changing PATH1 ---
Configuration.PATH1: c:\test
Configuration.PATH2: c:\production\subfolder      // <-- Hasn't changed

Assertion failed: 

assert Configuration.PATH2 == "c:\\test\\subfolder"
                     |     |
                     |     false
                     c:\production\subfolder
```

**Hypothesis**

It seems that `PATH2` is only set once at the very beginning when class `Configuration` is accessed for the first time.

I suppose that's the correct behaviour. Could anyone confirm this hypothesis?

Also: could you show me with a code example how it's done correctly? Is this how it should be done properly: by implementing a `getPATH2()` method?

```
class Configuration {
    static public String PATH1 = "c:\\production"
    static public String PATH2 = "${PATH1}\\subfolder"

    static public getPATH2() {
        return "${PATH1}\\subfolder"
    }
}
```

Is it correct that after the class `Configuration` has been instantiated, this is what it looks like in memory?

```
class Configuration {
    static public String PATH1 = "c:\\production"
    static public String PATH2 = "c:\\production\\subfolder" // Variable PATH1 has been resolved after class instantiation and is sort of "gone" so changing PATH1 has no effect on PATH2 anymore?

    static public getPATH2() {
        return "${PATH1}\\subfolder"
    }
}
```

Is it correct that the variable `PATH1` placeholder in the `PATH2` assignment has been resolved and is sort of "gone" so changing `PATH1` has no effect on `PATH2` anymore?

**Question summary**

1. Is the hypothesis correct?
2. What's the correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks... firstly your hypothesis is right. Second, I advice against the field, if you use a getter. That makes the property a read-only one, but the getter never sees changed values anyway.

Then there is an alternative to the getter, which is staying with a field, but to use a GString, instead. GString is lazy evaluated, and newly evaluated every time you ask for its value. And you actually already do that in:

```
class Configuration {
    static public String PATH1 = "c:\\production"
    static public String PATH2 = "${PATH1}\\subfolder"

    static public getPATH2() {
        return "${PATH1}\\subfolder"
    }
}
```

but if you assign a GString to a String, like you do in PATH2, you loose the lazy aspect. So a corrected version would be:

```
class Configuration {
    static public String PATH1 = "c:\\production"
    static final public GString PATH2 = "${PATH1}\\subfolder"
}
```

(I use final, because it makes no sense to keep mutability beyond the GString anymore)

Comment: Does your remark "newly evaluated every time you ask for its value" only belong to the first code example with `getPATH2()` in it and not the second code example with `GString PATH2`? When I take my code example and only change `String PATH2` to `GString PATH2`, the console output stays the same, i.e. `GString PATH2` does not get newly evaluated every time I ask for its value. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Because it was resolved when created and not updated later. This doesn't work in the way the every time You ask for `PATH2` is computed again and again. So your hypothesis is correct.

How to implement it? Assigning value to static field multiple times looks smelly. You should rather use normal (non static) fields with setters and getters. For `PATH2` only getter is required.